# using loop function to plot multiple columns

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot 2,695 different plots using the columns of my dataset. The x axis will be constant for all the datasets which is the "instrument.supersaturation" column. As for the y axis it will be the remaining columns label with date and times.

[image]

I have tried the following code to plot all 2,695 plots using the loop function. The code works and it shows the x-axis points as the instrument supersaturation values, but I'm having trouble plotting the y-axis using the concentrations of my column so it give a straight line on the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

col_names <- colnames(rotated.plot.data)
col_names <- col_names[-1]

for(i in col_names){
plot <- ggplot(rotated.plot.data, aes(x=rotated.plot.data$instrument.supersaturation, y="i"))+
geom_point()
print(plot)}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of a for loop, try `purrr::map(col_names , function (y) { ggplot(rotated.plot.data, aes(x=instrument.supersaturation, y={{ y }})) + geom_point() })`

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate it since I am just learning and didn't know about the purrr toolkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried it in your way. The error arises from - i in inverted commas as ggplot does not recognize it. sym function removes inverted commas and eval function will evaluate it as an expression.
Phils method would be much easier if you are familiar with map()

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

iris<-iris %>% select(-c(Species))

for(i in 1:(length(colnames(iris))-1)){
  plot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=eval(sym(colnames((iris[i+1]))))))+
    geom_point()
  print(plot)}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped explained why I was getting an error and as well how to make the code work